# Add new column to t1 (value from t2) based on column header conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server - table 1:

| a | b | c | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 1 | null | 150 |
| 2 | null | null | 151 |
| null | null | 2 | 152 |

There should always be 2 null and a value between columns a b and c.

Table 2:

| Column Name | Column Value | ID | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 1 | 150 | result1 |
| a | 2 | 151 | result2 |
| c | 2 | 152 | result3 |

I want to add a new column on table 1 called results with table 2 results when

1. table 1 ID = table 2 ID, and
2. table 1 with column name (that is not null) matches table 2 with corresponding volume value

I see solutions if say column = column across tables but am not sure how to also match column names. Thank you

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD results text;
                            
UPDATE table1
SET table1.results  = table2.result
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

But want to see:

Table 1:

| a | b | c | ID | results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 1 | null | 150 | results1 |
| 2 | null | null | 151 | results2 |
| null | null | 2 | 152 | results3 |

Comment: _"how I can improve!"_ - take time to format your question so that it's easier to read. There is help available in the editor for formatting tables, etc. It's worth doing.

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: And don't tag SSMS, that just a UI and no relevant on building a query.

Comment: It doesn't look like your table2 actually matches the end result, 150 has a =2 in table2 but a = null in table1

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your help and pointers. I edited table 2 to actually match the results, appreciate everyone's patience!

Comment: Storing column names in the data is _usually_ (though not always) a sign of a serious mistake with the schema design. It's hard to know for sure without knowing what this data represents, but based on what we can see I'd lean more on side of this schema being fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16#basic-pivot-example) table2 to give it the same structure as table1 and then it's a straightforward join.

The pivoted data shows why the first two rows won't produce the result you want based on the provided data.

Note that this may get unwieldy if you really need a lot more columns...

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (a INT NULL, b INT NULL, c INT NULL, ID INT, result VARCHAR(MAX) NULL);

INSERT INTO @table1 
VALUES (NULL, 1, NULL, 150, NULL),
        (2, NULL, NULL, 151, NULL),
        (NULL, NULL, 2, 152, NULL);

SELECT * FROM @table1;

DECLARE @table2 TABLE (name SYSNAME, value INT, ID INT, result VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES ('a', 2, 150, 'result1'),
        ('b', 1, 151, 'result2'),
        ('c', 2, 152, 'result3');

SELECT * FROM @table2;

/* Showing effect of PIVOT */
WITH t2pivoted
AS
(
SELECT [a], [b], [c], ID, result
FROM  @table2
PIVOT  
    (  
    MIN(Value)  
    FOR name IN ( [a], [b], [c])
    ) AS pvt
)
SELECT *
FROM t2pivoted;

/* Join in action - note that the first two rows in table 1 don't match */
WITH t2pivoted
AS
(
SELECT [a], [b], [c], ID, result
FROM  @table2
PIVOT  
    (  
    MIN(Value)  
    FOR name IN ( [a], [b], [c])
    ) AS pvt
)
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.ID, t2.result
FROM @table1 t1
    INNER JOIN t2pivoted t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
            AND (
                (t1.a = t2.a)
                OR (t1.b = t2.b)
                OR (t1.c = t2.c)
                )
```